# GitHub: Is there a way to programmatically file an issue?

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-api

Is there an API for filing a GitHub issue?

When I have an unexpected issue I would like to offer the user an option to automatically report an issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the GitHub API page which details how to programatically create an issue:

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

**Example, from the docs:**

Send a POST request to `/repos/:owner/:repo/issues` with JSON like the following:

```
{
  "title": "Found a bug",
  "body": "I'm having a problem with this.",
  "assignee": "octocat",
  "milestone": 1,
  "labels": [
    "Label1",
    "Label2"
  ]
}
```

You can also edit issues programatically by sending a PATCH request to `/repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number`

Source: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue

Answer (score 1):

You can also use (2021) the [GitHub CLI '`gh`'](https://cli.github.com/)

In your case: [`gh issue create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_create).

Example:

```
gh issue create --title "I found a bug" --body "Nothing works"
```

<sup>(Hopefully, your issue description would be slightly more detailed than that!)</sup>

Comment: What happens if the issue already exists? Does it make another one? Is there a way to +1 the issue?

Comment: @K-Dawg It should display an error message. What did you see when you tested that case?

Comment: I didn't try it I was asking you to elaborate on your answer before I invest any time on it. It's just a thought at the moment.

Comment: @K-Dawg After test, it does not show an error but (using https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue) creates a new issue. With the same title. In other words, "already exist" does not mean "same title". It just creates an additional new issue.